# Making anchor tag 100% height of parent on resize

Tags: html, css

I have navigation like this:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

and css is set as

```
ul {display:table;}
li {display:table-cell;}
a {display:block;}
```

However when I resize the screen my menu shrinks and some text breaks on the new line. Now that link is fine, however links that still occupy only one line are only for example padded : 10px 5px; and have parent element with empty space.

It looks very ugly as I have `:hover` that changes the BG color of an anchor ...

Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly the question is? Are you asking why the menu shrinks, or how to fix it etc?

Comment: change the background color of the li instead? li:hover {background-color:blue}

Answer (score 0):

so I think the problem is that when your first list item is multiple lines long, you do not like that the second list item is not vertically aligned with the first one. With the way you have the CSS set up, the list items are already all the same height, you just need to add a vertical align property so that it centers up.

So your li css should look like:

```
li {
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

You can check out my codepen for it [here](http://codepen.io/peteTalksWeb/pen/yNmPqL)

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely position the a tag to invisibly cover the entire cell. Now it has no effect on the cell's inner layout

```
li {
  position: relative
}

li a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```